# Wrong resolution using Dual Link DVI cable

Tags: resolution, dvi

I have Gigabyte GV-N98TSL-1GI videocard and Eizo FlexScan S2410W monitor.

They were connected using noname single link DVI cable. I took this DVI cable to connect a smaller monitor to other PC.

So I needed a DVI cable and I bought Cablexpert DVI Dual Link 1.8m (CC-DVI2-6C) cable. And when I connected S2410W with this cable, I saw a fuzzy image instead of clear one. nVidia panel shows that resolution is 1920x1200, but "Information" panel in monitor shows that resolution is 920x1200.

What's wrong? How do I fix this? Please help.

Comment: Have you tried the cable with other pc? Does it works correctly? Maybe the cable is faulty?

Comment: I can't yet find a PC with 24" monitor to check my cable with resolution 1920x1200.

I found out that it works with resolution 1600x1200 on my videocard with my monitor. Seems like it's not a Dual Link, but a Half-Link cable. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works perfectly with other monitor. Seems that Eizo FlexScan S2410W can't handle dual link cables.